# Designing function API that returns non-copyable struct in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to write functions that operate on graphs, which look like this:

```rust
#[derive(Hash, Eq, PartialEq, Copy, Clone)]
struct Node(usize);

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Graph {
    edges: HashMap<Node, HashMap<Node, usize>>
}
```

And one of my function is to combine two graphs in some way. So currently, the function declaration and implementations looks like:

```rust
fn combine(Graph a, Graph b) -> Graph {
    Graph::new(...)
}

impl BitOr for Graph {
    type Output = Self;

    fn bitor(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        combine(self, rhs)
    }
}
```

The intended outcome is that the following code would compile:

```rust
// Define A, B, C, D
let A = Graph { edges: [].into() };
let B = Graph { edges: [].into() };
let C = Graph { edges: [].into() };
let D = Graph { edges: [].into() };

let new_graph1 = A | B | C;
let new_graph1 = A | B | D;
```

However, since my Graph is not copyable, it means everytime I call the function, user has to do A.clone() | B.clone() | C.clone() | D.clone()`, which is not ideal.

The second attempt is passing in references. `combine` can't return a reference, since it cannot create a new Graph then return a reference to it, so it returns a Graph. However, when the user does something lik

```rust
impl BitOr for &Graph {
    type Output = Self;

    fn bitor(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        combine(self, rhs)
    }
}

// ...

// A = ...
// B = ...
// C = ...
D = &A | &B | &C
```

There will be an error, since `(&A | &B)` is a `Graph`.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I am new to Rust so I might be missing something, but I have tried for quite a while, and either I run into returning references (lifetime issues obviously), or the bitwise operation stops working, which is quite important for my use case.

Comment: Why the need to `clone()`? Does the user still need the graph after the `|`?

Comment: Is the problem with `clone()` performance, or convenience? Because if it is convenience, you can impl for both owned graphs and references and clone for them as needed.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes, I have added an example use case. Think of the ABCD as building blocks or "more complicated nodes", then the user reuse it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It's for convenience, since typing all the .clone() drove me crazy and probably other people using it won't be happy either :) I don't understand your second sentence of "impl for both owned graphs and references", do you mind explaining?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can impl `BitOr` for all combinations of references and owned values, and in `combine()` take whatever is easier/more performant. For example, with `combine()` taking references:

```rust
impl BitOr for Graph {
    type Output = Graph;
    fn bitor(self, other: Graph) -> Graph { combine(&self, &other) }
}
impl BitOr for &'_ Graph {
    type Output = Graph;
    fn bitor(self, other: &Graph) -> Graph { combine(self, other) }
}
impl BitOr<&'_ Graph> for Graph {
    type Output = Graph;
    fn bitor(self, other: &Graph) -> Graph { combine(&self, other) }
}
impl BitOr<Graph> for &'_ Graph {
    type Output = Graph;
    fn bitor(self, other: Graph) -> Graph { combine(self, &other) }
}
```

Now users can use whatever is most comfortable, and can chain: `&A | &B | &C` will work, for example.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. [This](https://github.com/grhkm21/rust-dfa-nfa-regex/blob/master/examples/div_3_regex.rs#L19:L31) is what it looks like right now. I suppose it is normal to still have references everywhere? (Since it is not copyable). Is there any way to make Rust just clone instead of copy for moving?

Comment: @GarethMa No, there is no such thing, but why do you take a reference to the final result?

Comment: Oh I kind of copy and pasted it, I guess that's not necessary, but the `dump_nfa` still takes a `&Nfa` anyways. I will stick with this for now, thanks!